# What will be the regular expression for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a string of "[195] shilpi is good girl [134]" how can i escape the [195] and [134] i tried many things but its not working out, i think because of [ ] this type of bracket as we use these brackets in regexp itself any help will be helpful.

Comment: You can use a regex like `\[.*?\]` to select data between `[` and `]` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regex `(\[\w+\])`

```
str = '[195] shilpi is good girl [134]'
regex = /(\[\w+\])/
gsubed_str = str.gsub(regex, "")
```

The output of gsubed_str is `" shilpi is good girl "` which is what I assume you needd